# expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <int K>
class Wrap
{
   // stuffs
};
```

What is wrong if I instantiate the template like `Wrap < 5>4 > p;`?
I get **expected unqualified-id before numeric constant** error. How to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is wrong if I instanciate the template like `Wrap < 5>4 > p;`?

That should be intuitively obvious just by looking at the statement: it’s confusing even for humans! The compiler has no way of coping with the double meaning of `>` here: does it mean “greater than”? Does it mean “close the template argument list”? Turns out, it means *both*, and the compiler has no hint as to which meaning to apply where. Both are technically valid parses.

Answer (score 13):

Change `Wrap < 5>4 > p;` to `Wrap < (5>4) > p;`

The first `>` encountered is taken as the end of the template argument list rather than greater than operator `>`

ISO C++ [14.2/3]

> When parsing a template-id, the first non-nested `>` is taken as the end of the template
>     argument-list rather than a greater-than operator.

Answer (score 2):

Ambiguity. Use Wrap<(5>4)> instead.